# Show item prices directly or not?

Tags: website-design, e-commerce, pricing

I'm creating a website for this company (this company is actually a gym).
They're also building an online store (for the membership plans).

I got this idea of putting the items with the prices and links to the online store item pages on the main page, (the store is on a different page) but the manager wasn't really sure of the idea.

[image: Prices]

From my experience, it's much nicer to see the price directly, not having to navigate through multiple links (which would be the idea of what the manager thought).

How is it?
Does it only drive the customers away or make them feel more comfortable with the company?

Comment: Depending on the client base, hiding the price is a sales tactic that can backfire. For myself, I'm price sensitive, and if you don't show the price up front, then I'm never going to dig and find it. I'll just assume you're too expensive and walk away.

Comment: Are you a gym-goer then, as they are obviously the main client base? I myself am not, but I also hate digging up the prices of items I'm interested in.

Comment: I belong to the local YMCA (it's certainly not the nicest gym around, but again, I'm price sensitive).

Comment: This gym is closer to high-quality than cheap. But it doesn't count out the price sensitive people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at this with the persona of a prospect gym goer. If I'm looking for a new gym, what are the things that matters? Location, equipment, facility services, price, environment.

What sort of clientele does this gym serve? Is this higher end or price sensitive? If the people you are targeting are price sensitive, you better be darn sure that pricing info is easy to find.

If this is a more full service gym with dedicated trainers, classes etc, then you might be able to get away with a "Come take a look. Your first visit is on us!" message and not bother with allowing users to buy membership online.

From what you posted, it doesn't seem like the latter is the case.

Comment: Actually, the gym offers the newest equipment within 50 miles, personal trainers, classes etc. so I think it's more of a high quality gym, rather than just a cheap place to work out at.

Comment: "not bother with allowing users to buy membership online." They also have an office at the gym where they sell these membership plans, but from his speech, I think more people buy the (at least renewals) memberships online.

Comment: Gotcha. So it's a decent gym but not an exclusive one. The online store section, will this be open to the public or behind a login? Doesn't matter if you can sign up right away.

Comment: Open to the public I think. At least their old one was. But a login system for returning customers could be nice. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I see. I'm just thinking if it's open to the public, what difference does it make that the prices are on a different page? You can bypass all that if you do a google search. If you have to put in an extra irrelevant road block that's kind of silly. On the other hand, if the gym does want to present itself as more exclusive as a business model, the pricing can be behind the login. And yeah, would be good if the system remembers customers. The login would need to be easy to remember though if they offer annual memberships. Like email + password (maybe membership # instead of password).

Comment: Majority of new customers arrive on the main page and are not looking for the online store before they've had enough information. Most of the people visiting the online store would be returning customers. Hiding the prices behind a login would be just evil. I, as a customer, wouldn't go that far just to see the prices.

Comment: Seems to me you want to show pricing directly. As to selling it to the manager, if you can, go ask people in the gym what matters for them when it comes picking a gym and to rank the importance. If price is consistently mentioned then I think you have sufficient support for your suggestion. Good luck with it!

Comment: You could think it's vice versa; If the prices are hidden, the customer could get a feeling their 'ashamed' of their pricing and don't have enough to offer for the money, while showing them on the first page is a risky move, it could give a feeling of confidence to the customer, like they have something to offer for the money. It's a bit expensive place, though. My local gym (which is just a gym, nothing more) costs about 3e/time and 100e/year. This one is 10e/time and about 500e/year.